# Where can I find Mechwarrior 3rd edition point buy system?

Tags: character-creation, product-identification

I am trying to find the alternate character generation rules for Mechwarrior 3rd edition that does not use life paths and instead just uses a point buy system. Looking to use the rules for another setting (FFG's Android setting) and the life path system will not work for it.

I know it was printed in a later book but I cannot recall which one and my group member who owned that book has since left.

If anyone knows which book it is in so I can begin hunting it down, it would be very helpful. Or if it was reprinted for Classic Battletech RPG even.

Answer (score 3):

Some diligent searching has uncovered the [Classic BattleTech Companion](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/Classic_BattleTech_Companion).  The book is from the FanPro era of BattleTech (it had 'Classic' in the title at it's first printing, unlike the 'Classic BattleTech RPG', which was a reprint of MechWarrior Third Edition), and covers the third edition of the RPG.  The book is currently not available on DriveThru or BattleCorps (May 2015).